# How to expose std::vector<int> as a Python list using SWIG?

Tags: c++, python, stl, swig

I'm trying to expose this function to Python using SWIG:

```
std::vector<int> get_match_stats();
```

And I want SWIG to generate wrapping code for Python so I can see it as a list of integers.

Adding this to the .i file:

```
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

namespace std
{
  %template(IntVector) vector<int>;
}
```

I'm running `SWIG Version 1.3.36` and calling swig with `-Wall` and I get no warnings.

I'm able to get access to a list but I get a bunch of warnings when compiling with `-Wall` (with `g++ (GCC) 4.2.4` ) the generated C++ code that say:

```
  warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
```

Am I exposing the function correctly? If so, what does the warning mean?

---

These are the lines before the offending line in the same function:

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_IntVector_erase__SWIG_0(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  std::vector *arg1 = (std::vector *) 0 ;
  std::vector::iterator arg2 ;
  std::vector::iterator result;
  void *argp1 = 0 ;
  int res1 = 0 ;
  swig::PySwigIterator *iter2 = 0 ;
  int res2 ;
  PyObject * obj0 = 0 ;
  PyObject * obj1 = 0 ;

  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,(char *)"OO:IntVector_erase",&obj0,&obj1)) SWIG_fail;
  res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj0, &argp1,SWIGTYPE_p_std__vectorT_int_std__allocatorT_int_t_t, 0 |  0 );
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(res1), "in method '" "IntVector_erase" "', argument " "1"" of type '" "std::vector *""'"); 
  }
  arg1 = reinterpret_cast * >(argp1);
```

And this is the offending line:

```
  res2 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(obj1, SWIG_as_voidptrptr(&iter2), swig::PySwigIterator::descriptor(), 0);
```

More code follows that.

The warning generated when compiling with g++ 4.2.4 is:

```
swig_iss_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_IntVector_erase__SWIG_0(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
swig_iss_wrap.cxx:5885: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
```

Comment: More recent swig version still generate code that cause warnings like this.  Use -fno-strict-aliasing to get g++ to accept the swig wrapper without issues.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
%template(IntVector) vector<int>;
```

Comment: That's what I tried and I get a bunch of warnings when compiling with g++. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of g++ are you using?  I'm using 4.1.2 and I don't get any warnings, even with -Wall.  I don't remember any warnings back when I was using 3.3 or so either.

Note the extra "<int>" in this post that's missing from the original post.

Comment: I'm using g++ 4.2.4 and trying to build with `-Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic`. I just tried building it with just -Wall and still get the warnings.

Comment: This might be a new 4.2-ism.  There have been some big changes under the hood with gcc 4.2.  Could you post the generated line of code that's creating this warning?

Comment: Here is the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276769/how-to-expose-stdvectorint-as-a-python-list-using-swig#287580

Comment: See if you can hunt down the definition for SWIG_ConvertPtr (or run the cxx file through the gcc preprocessor to see what that expands to).  I'm guessing that it's a macro that needs to be rewritten.  Also, take a look at

http://mail.opensolaris.org/pipermail/tools-gcc/2005-August/000047.html

Comment: Some of the older versions of SWIG generate sloppy code. GCC 4.2 doesn't like a lot of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with Swig, but are you #including your C++ header file in your .i file? Try one (or both) of

```
%include "myvector.h"


%{
#   include "myvector.h"
%}
```