# How do I access List template of C++ program from Perl using SWIG?

Tags: perl, swig

I want to access a template List of C++ program from a Perl script and use those values.

Example code:

```
typedef list < Struct1  * > sturct1_list;

struct Struct2
{
    int i;
    struct1_list List1;
}

struct Struct1
{
    int j;
}
```

I used one swig generated api and did the following:

```
$myList = Struct2_struct1List_get 
print "Reference type: " . ref($myList) ;
```

now this prints as:

```
Reference type:  \_p\_std\_\_listTutils\_\_Struct1\_p\_t
```

how to get the values from the structure using this?

#### Update from duplicate question:

in interface file i put

```
%template(ListStruct1) std::list< Struct1 * >;
```

after i generate the ".pm" file. I checked the APIs available this list.

I found

```
ListStuct1_size
ListStuct1_empty
ListStuct1_clear
ListStuct1_push.
```

I was able to use those elements. But i dont know how to access individual elements of the list using these API? or am I missing something in interface file?

UPDATED:

Is typemap possible to return the list as array here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First of all, general info

[This tutorial](http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html) shows how to do the wrapper for templates.

The same tutorial shows how to use the module from Perl, but the perl example doesn't touch templates.

[This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276769/how-to-expose-stdvectorint-as-a-python-list-using-swig) shows how to do that with a Vector

[Here's a general SWIG STL documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Library.html#Library_nn15) that seems to mention *[std_list.i](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/swig/swig-4/swig/Lib/perl5/std_list.i)* interface.

### Second, regarding lists

1. You can not "access" C++ list like a Perl array, by a subscript. If you wanted that, you must use a Vector as underlying type.
2. As an alternate, create a class extending List, give it a new method which returns an element by an index, and expose that method in an interface.
3. If you wish to access the list by finding an element, like in C++, you need to write a List interface that exposes find() method - the default one does not from reading the source code.

Comment: hi.. i read the documetation.. but i still confused how will access that list from perl?

Comment: You can't "access" the data in a list from perl since the default list interface doesn't expose any way for you to do so. See my updates in the answer for 3 possible solutions, depending on what you need.

Comment: can we do    %typemap(out) list<Struct1 *> {

}          and return it as an array??

Comment: You probably can, but I'm not quite sure of the purpose of having a list in C++ side (as opposed to the vector) if you merely turn it into vector-like Perl array?

Answer (score 1):

In your interface, try:

```
%include "std_list.i"

%template(ListStruct1) std::list< Struct1 * >;
```

The std library is kinda funny, there's no actual binary object called list that swig can just wrap, it's all templates - so swig needs some extra help to figure out what's going on.

That should add insert, remove, and a bunch of other list specific functions to the wrapper.

If the above doesn't work, try adding:

```
%define SWIG_EXPORT_ITERATOR_METHODS
```

UPDATE: Of course, I neglected to mention (or even realize) that this works great for python, java, and a few others, but is totally broken in perl...

Comment: Without a std_list.i supporting perl, you're limited to size, empty, clear, push. I tested with swig 1.3.39. Vector, however, gives push, pop, get, set - which might actually be useful.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i have not tried the %define directive that specified.. but i want that to work in perl.. anyways I will just  try that out..