# Wrapping std::vector of boost::shared_ptr in SWIG for Python

Tags: c++, python, vector, swig, shared-ptr

**EDIT:** Solved, my mistake; explained in my answer.

I have this:

```
std::vector < boost::shared_ptr < Entity > > entities;
```

and I try to expose it through SWIG like this:

```
%include "boost_shared_ptr.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

%shared_ptr(Entity)
%include <Entity.h>

namespace std {
    %template(EntityVector) vector<boost::shared_ptr<Entity> >;
};

%include <TheFileWithEntities.h>
```

However, in Python entities ends up being a tuple:

```
import MyModule
print type(MyModule.cvar.entities)
# Output: (type 'tuple')
```

I've Googled for this, but could not find any concrete examples on how to wrap this. One page gave a small example for wrapping it for C#, but it didn't help in my case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIG seems to wrap global variables of type std::vector into tuples. The solution is to move entities into a class, and access it through an instance of that class. Example:

```
class Globals
{
public:
     std::vector < boost::shared_ptr < Entity > > entities;
};

extern Globals globals;
```

Answer (score 5):

I had some difficulty getting a Python sequence of pointer objects to automatically convert into a `std::vector` of pointer objects.  I am currently (stuck) using Swig 1.3; YMMV if you're using Swig 2.  The trick was to instantiate in the Swig interface file (with `%template`) not just the vector, and not just the object, but the pointer objects also:

```
%include "std_vector.i"
%template(myObjectT) namespace::of::myObject<T>;
%template(myObjectPtrT) boost::shared_ptr<namespace::of::myObject<T> >;
%template(myObjectVectorT) std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<namespace::of::myObject<T> > >;
```

Without the `myObjectPtrT`, Swig doesn't seem to know enough to convert a Python sequence of pointers to `myObjectT` to a `myObjectVectorT`.

UPDATE: For some reason I haven't yet been able to figure out, this leads to not being able to call methods on `myObjectT` from a `myObjectPtrT`, even though I've also used `SWIG_SHARED_PTR(myObjectT, myObject<T>)`.

Comment: I should mention that our project has moved from SWIG to pybind11, which is much less obscure.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to expose std::vector<int> as a Python list using SWIG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276769/how-to-expose-stdvectorint-as-a-python-list-using-swig) for probably good info

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as you can see in my question, I already know how to wrap an std::vector. The issue is wrapping an std::vector of boost::shared_ptr's. SWIG seems to expose it as a tuple because it can't figure out the shared_ptr part of it.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've read that, but I didn't see anything relevant. Again, I can wrap boost::shared_ptr and I can wrap std::vector, and those work as expected. The issue is specifically std::vector < boost::shared_ptr < Entity > >, which shows up in Python as a tuple. Python can access the tuple, view the things inside of it, manipulate the individual Entities inside the tuple, but it can't append or modify it ... because it's a tuple.

Comment: I figured out the issue and edited my question with the solution. Thank you for taking the time to help!