# tuple is returned by python wrapper generated by swig for a C++ vector

Tags: python, c++, swig

For the following C++ API:

```
std::vector<float> get_sweep_points()
{
    return program->sweep_points;
}
```

Swig generates a wrapper which returns a tuple **()**, rather than a list **[]**. Why? How can I force Swig to return a list to python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expose std::vector<int> as a Python list using SWIG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276769/how-to-expose-stdvectorint-as-a-python-list-using-swig)

Comment: In my interface file, I already have %template(vectorf) vector<float>; but it is still returning a tuple instead of list.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `std_vector.i`, you get typemaps as implemented by `std_vector.i`. If you don't like it, you have to write your own typemaps.

Here's a typemap to override the default behavior (no error checking) and return a list instead of a tuple:

```
%typemap(out) std::vector<int> (PyObject* obj) %{
    obj = PyList_New($1.size());
    for(auto i = 0; i < $1.size(); ++i)
        PyList_SET_ITEM(obj, i, PyLong_FromLong($1[i]));
    $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, obj);
%}
```

Of course you can also just do `v = list(get_sweep_points())` and now it is a list :^)